# Is it possible to name the x and y axes in a matplotlib hexbin diagram?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can generate a hexbin diagram like this (code taken from http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/hexbin_demo.html)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import  matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 100000
x = np.random.standard_normal(n)
y = 2.0 + 3.0 * x + 4.0 * np.random.standard_normal(n)
xmin = x.min()
xmax = x.max()
ymin = y.min()
ymax = y.max()

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5)
plt.subplot(121)
plt.hexbin(x,y, cmap=cm.jet)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("Hexagon binning")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('counts')

plt.subplot(122)
plt.hexbin(x,y,bins='log', cmap=cm.jet)
plt.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.title("With a log color scale")
cb = plt.colorbar()
cb.set_label('log10(N)')

plt.show()
```

Is there any way to label the x and y axes of the hexbin with axis names?  I want something like "x-label" to show up below the x axis numbers, and "ylabel" to show up to the left of the y axis numbers.  This will be in addition to the label on the colorbar.

Comment: `plt.xlabel('x-label')`, `plt.ylabel('ylabel')`?

Comment: that works! answer and ill accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`xlabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel) and [`ylabel`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel) matplotlib commands:

```
plt.xlabel('x-label')
plt.ylabel('y-label')
```